# I can't downcast in JPQL/Hibernate - Unable to find domain.Scoreable with id 16

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, jpql

I have an abstract class called `Scoreable` and it's extended by two classes named `Idea` and `Solution`. That is, both subclasses may have a set of scores. Every `Score` has a field `scoreable` that is a FK.

What I want to get is a collection of Scores given, for example, an Idea. So I've tried the following query:

> select s from Score s join s.scoreable idea where idea.id = 16;

But it returns `Unable to find domain.Scoreable with id 16`, maybe because the Scoreable table doesn't exist in the database. Also I tried a downcast with this query `select s from Score s join TREAT(s.scoreable AS Idea) idea where idea.id = 16;`. In this case, I get the same response.

Comment: Could you please add your entities mapping?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be because you mapped the Scorable with @MapedSuperclass and now you want to include the base type in a query. For this you need the base class to be an actual @Entity instead.

According to the JPA documentation:

> A mapped superclass is a non-entity class that can define persistent state and mapping information for entity subclasses. Mapped
>   superclasses are usually abstract. Unlike true entities, you cannot
>   query a mapped superclass, pass a mapped superclass instance to any
>   EntityManager or Query methods, or declare a persistent relation with
>   a mapped superclass target. You denote a mapped superclass with the
>   MappedSuperclass marker annotation.

So you can have Scorable as both the base class and an @Entity, while its subclases idea dn Solution are @Entities too.For more about this inheritance model, check this [JPA example from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13981_01/cmp30cfg016.htm).

If you only need Idea's scores you can issue the following query:

```
select distinct s 
from Idea i
join i.scores s
where i.id = ?
```

Comment: Nope, I mapped the class with @Entity.

Comment: Same error: `Unable to find domain.Scoreable with id 16` (or whatever number that is Idea). :/ It may be because in MySQL doesn't exist a table called `Scoreable`, but instead each one of its subclasses has a table with the inherited fields.

Comment: If Scoreable is an actual @Entity it must have a table. You also need to add Scoreable to the Hibernate mapping or persistence.xml. If you don't have it then Hibernate can't know it's an entity.

Comment: It was because the class had the annotation `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`, so I changed this to `InheritanceType.JOINED` Now everything works perfectly, apparently.

Comment: According to the docs "When the concrete subclass is not known, the related object could be in any of the subclass tables, making joins through the relation impossible. This ambiguity also affects identity lookups and queries"